# Dust Under the Doors

Tags: ford, maintenance

Last year, we purchased 2010 Ford Taures Limited.  We live on a gravel road & must drive on it for approximately 2 miles before we hit pavement.
The drier the road becomes, the dustier it is.  This dust is coming in under all 4 doors; it is worse under the back doors.  The trunk seems unaffected.  The rubber gaskets on the bottom of the doors appear to be in good shape - no tears or holes.
Is there any kind of stripping or flasing that could be attached to the body of the car to prevent the dust from coming into the car!
Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Bueller? Bueller?

Answer (score 1):

The seals may be worn or *deflated* (not as puffy as they used to be) and are allowing the dust to come through. As a fix, you could try something (vs replacement) I saw on a TV show recently. They added a slender piece of rubber inside of the seal to make it stick out more. Something like this:

[image: Image pulled from zoro.com]

This is 1/4" tubing. The seal should have an air gap inside of it which you can stuff this down. You'd have to find the end of the seal to accomplish this. You may need to lube it up a little as well. If you cannot find an end where you can stuff it into, you may need to create an end with a sharp razor blade. If you take this route, make sure you have some good super glue around to mend the pieces back together.

Comment: Important to note that one should use silicone lube, not petroleum-based, on rubber.